# Implement logout on every page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, logout

I want to implement **logout** option on every view of my webpage.For this i assigned **null** to my **session variable**. And also remove the data in **cache**. But I studied that to remove the data from cache put some extra **burden**  on web server because no data is stored in cache...
So, what can be alternative to this problem.

Comment: You want to provide a Logout button in every page or user will logout automatically after reaching to each page ??

Comment: To implement logout, you can use master page. After clicking on log out, you clear session and redirect to login page

Comment: i want to implement logout on every page @BasantaMatia

Comment: you are exactly right @Vignesh but problem is that data is stored in cache and i don't want this .

Comment: Why are you go for cache, can't you do with the help of session alone

Answer (score 0):

Create a **_Layout page** and keep your Login/Register/Logout there. You can check by creating a default Web MVC application and see how login/register/logout rendering in every page.

There are many ways to clean cache by using java script.
I like this way,

```
<script>
 function ClearHistory()
  {
    var backlen = history.length;
    history.go(-backlen);
    window.location.href = loggedOutPageUrl //Pass your Index Page
  }
</script>
```

Or else the easiest way is just clear the cache in LogOff() method, just like bellow,

```
{
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Please check this [Link](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/135121/browser-back-button-issue-after-logout.aspx) There are many way to clear cache, so that **back button** will not work after logout.